# Having Troubles With Terraria

Tags: games, steam

I absolutely love this game and stupidly, I changed the file name, and now it doesn't work no matter how many times I delete, uninstall, or reinstall the game. I'm doing this through Steam. If you could help I would be extremely appreciative :D

BTW: I have tried, restarting computer, changing back file name, deleting all game files, uninstalling game, deleting game, reinstalling game. No matter what happens it will always crash after clicking single player.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a test, like this:

```
mv ~/.steam/ ~/.steam-old
```

then launch steam, re-login-in.